# Top-down space flight physics - AddForce - Object moves off center the faster it goes

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, game-physics

I just started a little project where I want the player to control a ship from a top-down perspective. I want the whole thing to use physics-based movement.

My problem is that when I add force to a rigidbody, the object it is attached to seems to move off its position the more the faster it goes. However, transform.positions seem to be alright.

I put together [this little unity package](https://www.dropbox.com/s/6gdn1gm2u1rezvl/TestInput.zip?dl=0). If you press W, the ship will move upwards and off the center the longer you press W. S moves in the other direction.

The code is rather simple:

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;

public class TestController : MonoBehaviour {
  public float mainThrust = 100;
  private Vector3 cameraOffset = new Vector3(0f, 0f, 150f);
  private new Rigidbody rigidbody;

  void Start () {
    rigidbody = GetComponent<Rigidbody>();
  }

  void FixedUpdate() {
    float axisVertical = Input.GetAxis("Vertical");
    Vector2 force = new Vector2(0f, axisVertical) * mainThrust * Time.fixedDeltaTime;
    rigidbody.AddRelativeForce(force, ForceMode.Impulse);
    Camera.main.transform.position = rigidbody.transform.position - cameraOffset;
    Debug.Log("camPos: " + Camera.main.transform.position
      + " - rbPos: " + rigidbody.transform.position);
  }
}
```

Any help appreciated.

Thanks,
Nico

Comment: It would help if you could provide screenshots/video of this as I'm not 100% sure of what your issue is. However, I suspect that your camera is simply lagging behind your gameobject due to the execution order of your scripts, I could be wrong though.

Comment: btw, you can make the camera a child of the ship and it will follow it automagically.

Comment: [Video](https://youtu.be/12z526xrUpM) coming. Camera seems not to be the problem. Attaching the camera to the object leads to the same behavior.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply put your `Camera.main.transform.position = rigidbody.transform.position - cameraOffset;` line in **LateUpdate** MonoBehaviour method and you'll be good I think (if I understood the problem correctly). You can look for [this](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/ExecutionOrder.html) if you need further explanations.

**EDIT :**

Here's the script I used to get the desired result (based on the one found in your package) :

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;

public class TestController : MonoBehaviour
{
    public float mainThrust = 100;
    private Vector3 cameraOffset = new Vector3(0f, 0f, 150f);
    private new Rigidbody rigidbody;

    private Vector3 tmpV1 = new Vector3(0f, 0f, 0f);
    private Vector3 tmpV2 = new Vector3(0f, 0f, 0f);

    // Draw debug cross at camera position
    private void drawX()
    {
        tmpV1.x = Camera.main.transform.position.x - 10f;
        tmpV1.y = Camera.main.transform.position.y;
        tmpV2.x = Camera.main.transform.position.x + 10f;
        tmpV2.y = Camera.main.transform.position.y;
        Debug.DrawLine(tmpV1, tmpV2, Color.red);
        tmpV1.x = Camera.main.transform.position.x;
        tmpV1.y = Camera.main.transform.position.y - 10f;
        tmpV2.x = Camera.main.transform.position.x;
        tmpV2.y = Camera.main.transform.position.y + 10f;
        Debug.DrawLine(tmpV1, tmpV2, Color.red);
    }

    void Start()
    {
        rigidbody = GetComponent<Rigidbody>();
    }

    void FixedUpdate()
    {
        float axisVertical = Input.GetAxis("Vertical");
        // impulse force in Newton
        Vector2 force = new Vector2(0f, axisVertical) * mainThrust * Time.fixedDeltaTime;
        rigidbody.AddRelativeForce(force, ForceMode.Impulse);
    }

    void LateUpdate()
    {
        Camera.main.transform.position = rigidbody.transform.position - cameraOffset;
        drawX();
        Debug.Log("camPos: " + Camera.main.transform.position + " - rbPos: " + rigidbody.transform.position);
    }
}
```

Comment: Sorry, doesn't help. :(

Comment: @NicoBüttner Well I just tried it with an empty project and the package you provided and it worked well... Are your sure you didn't made a typo on `LateUpdate()` ? Have you deleted the line you copied to LateUpdate ?

Comment: Are you very sure that it works for you? I tested on two systems now and the behavior is the same. To clarify things I uploaded a video (https://youtu.be/12z526xrUpM) to youtube. I want the cube to stay in the middle of the screen on the red cross. And have a look at the console: Camera.main.position and rigidbody.position are the same...

Comment: I just tested again and it work perfectly : you can see it [here](http://i.giphy.com/l0HlQfmfOHzArODmM.gif) (heavy .gif file). I edited my answer to give you the code I used to achieve this.

Comment: Im am so very sorry! I still drew the cross in the FixedUpdate method and so it looked like the same behavior but actually the cross fell behind the correct positioning of the camera. Actually I do not even have to put it in the LateUpdate method but can just use the Update method. So is it correct that when I apply force to an object in the FixedUpdate method, the actual positioning of the objects is resolved somewhere between FixedUpdate and Update?

Comment: @NicoBüttner No problem don't worry : as a matter of fact I kind of guess this was your error since I also made it at first (moving only the said line and not the cross drawing thing). I'm glad you worked it out ! Best luck for the remaining parts of your game :)